# How to Solve this Differential Calculus Problem

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

If the equation of the normal line to the curve $y = ax + b/x$ at the point $(2,7)$ is $y+ 2x = 11$, find the value of $a$ and $b$. Given that this normal line meets the curve again at $P$, find the coordinates of $P$.

I found the tangent equation to be $y= 1/2 x + 6$. I inegrated that to get $y = x^2 /4 + 6x + c$. Then I found c by putting the values of the point  in as 6.

(I am unsure from here forward) I think $ax + b/x$ would be $ax^2 + yx + b$ , meaning $a$ would be $1/4$ and $b$ would be -7.

I do not know what to do to find the other intersection of the normal, given that I am unsure that my answers for $a$ and $b$ are accurate

Comment: Can you show us what you have attempted? Or what is interesting about this question?  Usually questions posed with the tone "do this homework problem for me" are not well-received.

Comment: I found the tangent equation to be y= 1/2 x + 6. I inegrated that to get y = x^2 /4 + 6x + c. Then I found c by putting the values of the point  in as -6.

Comment: (I am unsure from here forward) I think ax+b/x would be ax2+yx+b , meaning a would be 1/4 and b would be -6.

I do not know what to do to find the other intersection of the normal, given that I am unsure that my answers for a and b are accurate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)=ax+b/x \implies f'(x)=a-b/x^2$ 
And we know that $f(2)=7$ and (by your computation) $f'(2)=1/2$

So then $7= 2a+b/2$ and $1/2=a-b/4$. I think we should be able to solve the system of equations for $a$ and $b$.

We find $(a,b)=(2,6)$ and we can confirm this by checking out the [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vgepco5nxu).

[image]

Comment: So I just went the wrong way by integrating the tangent eqaution instead of differentiating the equation of the curve?

Comment: Yes. Integration isn't the way to go here because while you know your curve is tangent at that point. The tangent line isn't going to communicate any information about the curve in general.

Comment: I see, thank you